# In using FLASK CSRF cookies how can I validate the actual CSRF

Tags: flask, flask-jwt-extended

In using with CSRF in Flask the checkauth route is saying "fine" and allowing this to go through....is the CSRF getting checked automatically or do I need to do something specific?

In addition how would I check the CSRF...seems like a lot of FLASK documentation says hey use this double check but then fails to show how to check it.

```
@login_blu.route('/login',methods=['GET'])
def login():
    username = 'milei'
    access_token = create_access_token(identity=username)
    refresh_token = create_refresh_token(identity=username)

    # Set the JWT cookies in the response
    resp = jsonify({'login': True})
    set_access_cookies(resp, access_token)
    set_refresh_cookies(resp, refresh_token)
    return resp, 200
    return jsonify({'login':'values'})

    @login_blu.route('/checkauth',methods=['GET'])
    @jwt_required()
    def checkauth():
    # Set the JWT cookies in the response
    
        return jsonify({'test':'test'})
```